# Mention gis.stackexchange.com in the gis tag description

Tags: feature-request, tags

Could the existence of http://gis.stackexchange.com be mentioned in the description of the GIS tag on this site? That might cause askers to realise it exists and it might be a better place for their question.

Suggested additional text: "A dedicated site for GIS questions, gis.stackexchange.com, might be a better place to ask GIS-related questions"

Comment: I like the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a great idea and can't think of any downsides, as long as it's clear.

Selecting tags is part of the process when first composing a question and happens before the question even gets posted. If it serves to suggest that the question might better be asked in GIS, the post author has a chance to stop before it gets posted here and post there instead.

Especially if "consider asking there **instead**" is an explicit part of the wiki excerpt.

This can potentially save days, work by users and moderators (migration), frustration and even acrimony, so it really seems like a good idea.

I'd say go for it!

Comment: I've just altered the tag.

Comment: @Fred that looks good to me. In Space SE and Astronomy SE I think the mods like to update the tag of the meta question to `status:completed` to show that action has been taken, but not sure if the mods here like to do the same.

Comment: I just tried to add the tag to the meta question, but not being a mod my request was denied. We'll have to wait for the mods to complete the change.